# Does AIX support SIOCGLIFCONF?

Tags: unix, ipv6, aix, ioctl

To probe network adapter properties in IPv4, we can use SIOCGIFONF, SIOCGIFNETMASK etc.
On HP-UX and Solaris, the IPv6 equivalents are SIOCGLIFONF, SIOCGLIFNETMASK.

Does AIX support these ioctls (perhaps with an APAR) or are they called something different?

A pointer to a standards document would be helpful - I googled but didn't find anything.

Comment: Just `grep` the headers on AIX?

Comment: After grepping, I can see that there is SIOCGIFCONF (no *LIFCONF) but there is SIOGIFNETMASK and SIOGIFNETMASK6 which implies that some ioctl calls are specifically for v6 and some (like SIOCGFICONF) are mixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM's website implies the standard `SIOCGIFCONF` on AIX like Linux is IP family independent as it uses `struct sockaddr`.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ioctl-socket.html

Comment: Thanks.. but not a great page. Some of the code needs to fixed before it will compile (and I don't mean add includes)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a separate [SIOCGIFCONF6](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1PK22885) that was added to support IPv6.  Not sure how to tell what version of AIX may have it.